# Mount shared folder on windows on linux redhat 5.5

Tags: cifs

I mount shared folder win server 2012 on Linux red hat 5.5 64 bit,

```
mount.cifs \\\\misaddress\\shared folder \backup\ -o username=username
```

After created it successfully, I can do anything WITH IT READ WRITE ...
I CANNOT CHANGE OWNER or  GROUP  ON \backup\

```
Chown: changing  ownership of \backup\: permission denied
```

Comment: redhat linux 5 only went to 5.2 and was released in 1997 - are you sure you don't mean some other distribution?

Comment: red hat enterprise linux  server  release 5.5 (Tikanga)